# How to do a pull --rebase only on the current branch

Tags: mercurial

I want to execute a `hg pull -b [branch] --rebase` where `[branch]` is whatever branch I'm currently on.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I ended up with (for PowerShell):

`hg pull -r $(& hg branch) --rebase`

Comment: Pure HG solution in revset `-r "branch(.)"`

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  I get the error "abort: repository branch(. not found!"